# Converting Sql query (update table set ....) to linq ( var m = ...)

Tags: sql, linq

I am trying to write a linq query in my Database.cs file. I find it difficult. Is there any tool to convert sql to linq? I tried linqer but it is no good. Or could you help me in writing the following query in linq.

```
update table 
set field1='R', 
    field2='" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss") + "', 
    field3 = '" + util.CleanStringInput(value1) + "'
where field1 = 'P' 
    and field3 = '" + value2 + "' 
    and field4 = (select max(field5) 
                  from table2 
                  where field6='" + value2 + "')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to fetch the entities, set the properties and then save changes:

```
var maxFromTable2 = context.YourTables2.
                            Where(t2 => t2.field6 == value2).
                            Max(t2 => t2.field5);

var entitiesToUpdate = context.YourTables.
                               Where(t => t.field1 == "P" && 
                                          t.field3 == value2 && 
                                          t.field4 ==  maxFromTable2).
                               ToList();

foreach (var entityToUpdate in entitiesToUpdate)
{
    entityToUpdate.field1 = "R";
    entityToUpdate.field2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

NOTE: It is not clear from your question what table you are updating, so I assume by default that it is a table different from `table2`. It could help if you indicate whether you are using LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework (LINQ to Entitites). The current syntax is for EF.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL/EF are intended to hydrate objects and operate on those, saving the changes. It is not intended as a replacement for batch operations. If you use EF/LINQ to SQL in this case, you will be issuing n+1 requests to the database: 1 to select the records you are going to change and a separate request for each row (object) you are updating. With a small data set, this may be managable, but if you have any kind of volume, keeping this in a stored proc using a single Update statement may be a better option.